# User Login (If statement trouble)

Tags: database, user-interface, if-statement, authentication

I have successfully made a login screen and database table for users, all working apart from: When admin is logged in, he is transferred to Admins UI, every one else should be transferred to client UI.
   In my case all users go to Admins UI.
       Would appreciate any help.

```
if (target == loginButton) {

        String sql = "select * from details";

        try {

            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {



                String usr=rs.getString("User");

                System.out.println("User:..."+usr);



                System.out.println("Logging In...");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Account is loading...");



                if (usr.equals("adminn")){

                    UserAdmin ua = new UserAdmin("Admins Interface");

                    ua.setVisible(true);

                  } 

                  else{

                    User_Patient up = new User_Patient("User Interface");

                    up.setVisible(true);

                    }

            } else {

                System.out.println("Failure Login...");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Details...");



                }

        } catch (Exception e1) {

            System.out.println("Database Connectivity Error...");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on the if statement. Then run the project in debug mode. When it stops at the breakpoint, you can press F8 to step through the code. This way you can see if the program behaves as expected. You can also hover the mouse over a variable to see its value (unless the variable is a object, then it will show a reference).

Answer (score 0):

"Sorted"

```
if (target == loginButton) {
        String username= LUserTF.getText();
        String password=LPassTF.getText();
        String sql = "select * from details where User= '" + username + "' and Pass='"+password+"'";

        try {

            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {

                String usr = rs.getString("User");
                String pwd = rs.getString("Pass");

                System.out.println("User:..." + usr);

                System.out.println("Logging In...");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Your Account is loading...");

                if (usr.equals("adminn")&&pwd.equals("root")) {

                    UserAdmin ua = new UserAdmin("Admins Interface");

                    ua.setVisible(true);

                }

                else {

                    User_Patient up = new User_Patient("User Interface");

                    up.setVisible(true);

                }

            } else {

                System.out.println("Failure Login...");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Details...");

            }

        } catch (Exception e1) {

            System.out.println("Database Connectivity Error...");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);

        }

    }
```